# Optimizing sum of squared series

Tags: matrices, optimization

Suppose I have a matrix $X$ where each column is a particular random series. I would like to find a weight vector $w^{T}$ so that $\sum_{i} (w^{T}x_{i})^{2}$ is maximal where $x_{i}$ is the $i$th column of $X$. How can I solve a problem like this? The coefficients of the vector should sum to 1.

Comment: do you mean that each column is a realization of a random series?

Comment: Do the weights have to satisfy some criterion? The objective seems unbounded if the weights go to infinity.

Comment: Assuming that $w_i$ is a scalar your sum is still a vector so what do you mean by maximal?

Comment: Yes, each column is a realization of random series. Sorry, it was supposed to be a weight vector. Its coefficients should sum to 1.

Comment: The term you are trying to maximize, i.e. $\sum_i (w^Tx_i)^2$ is a R.V., so it is not meaningful to talk about maximizing it. Are you trying to find the optimal $w$ for a given $X$. If so, why is the randomness of $x_i$ relevant? ?If not, then do you want to maximize the expected value of your summation?